# How allow multiple search with ngx-datatable

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I'm using this https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/basic/filter.component.ts to help me create a search in my table.

My goal is to create an advanced search : filter by both gender and name value

```
  rows = [
{ name: 'Austin', gender: 'Male', company: 'Swimlane' },
{ name: 'Dany', gender: 'Male', company: 'KFC' },
{ name: 'Molly', gender: 'Female', company: 'Burger King' },
];
columns = [
{ prop: 'name' },
{ name: 'Gender' },
{ name: 'Company' }
];

@ViewChild(DatatableComponent) table: DatatableComponent;

temp=[]

constructor() {
    this.temp = this.rows;
}

updateFilter(event) {
    const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

    const temp = this.temp.filter(function (d) {
        return d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
    });

    this.rows = temp;
 }

 updateFilter1(event) {
  const val = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

  const temp = this.temp.filter(function (d) {
      return d.gender.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val;
  });
  this.rows = temp;
}
```

I just copy my search creating a second function filtering by gender. However, both search works separately (erasing the restriction of the other) and I don't know how to fix it.

Here you can find my `html` :

```
<input
    type='text'
    style='padding:8px;margin:15px auto;width:30%;'
    placeholder='Type to filter the name column...'
    (keyup)='filterByName($event)'
  />
  <input
    type='text'
    style='padding:8px;margin:15px auto;width:30%;'
    placeholder='Type to filter the name column...'
    (keyup)='filterByGender($event)'
  />
  <ngx-datatable
    #table
    class='material'
    [columns]="columns"
    [columnMode]="'force'"
    [headerHeight]="50"
    [footerHeight]="50"
    [rowHeight]="'auto'"
    [limit]="10"
    [rows]='rows'>
  </ngx-datatable>
```

Comment: Do you want do separate inputs or one input that checks on both?

Comment: I prefer separate input to allow me create search in several columns

Comment: Ok easy enough. Have each filter when called, save it's value it's going to filter on in some variable up top. Then when they run, they will also filter on whatever the other one last ran on. Let me know if that was a bad explanation and I'll write up some code.

Comment: It's very clear but I don't know how to create this variable which will keep my first search. I will try it, if you can give me some codes with, it would be perfect.

Comment: Ok give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
... // other vars you already have
previousNameFilter = ''
previousGenderFilter = ''

filterByName(event) {
  const filter = event.target.value
  this.previousNameFilter = filter
  this.temp = this.filterRows(filter, this.previousGenderFilter)
}

filterByGender(event) {
  const filter = event.target.value
  this.previousGenderFilter = filter
  this.temp = this.filterRows(this.previousNameFilter, filter)
}


filterRows(nameFilter, genderFilter): any[] {
  nameFilter = nameFilter.toLowerCase()
  genderFilter = genderFilter.toLowerCase()

  return this.rows.filter(row => {
    const isPartialNameMatch = row.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(nameFilter) !== -1 || !nameFilter
    const isPartialGenderMatch = row.gender.toLowerCase().indexOf(genderFilter) !== -1 || !genderFilter
    return isPartialNameMatch && isPartialGenderMatch
  });
}
```

[Stackblitz used for testing](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jsws3b)

Comment: Whoops. Forgot to say 'const filter' in those two functions. Good chance there are typos as I didn't actually run this code. Not sure what you comment means about this.previousNameFilter and this.previousGenderFilter (also not sure if you spelled them wrong on purpose)

Comment: I think we must add to `previousNameFilter` in the function filterByGender the prefix `this.previousNameFilter`. Same way for filterByName.

Comment: Ohhhh you are correct. My mistake for not understanding you

Comment: It's me, thanks a lot for your help. Unfortunately, both searches do nothing now. :(

Comment: :D well that is no good. Can you post the html for the inputs/table?

Comment: Found the problem, it was with my code. I forgot to convert the value in the row I was checking to lower case.

Comment: I also added a code example (it doesn't have the literal table, but it will log the result of the filters

Comment: Nothing again ... :( I will look on Stackblitz how to fix it.

Comment: Oh! Its because your table is not reading the rows from temp. Look at the table html

Answer (score 1):

Little late, but here's a generic function to partially match any field.

```
updateFilter(event) {
    const input = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

    // filter our data
    if (input.length > 0) {
      const filtered = this.rows
        .filter(el =>
          Object.values(el).find(
            val =>
              val.toString()
                .toLowerCase()
                .indexOf(input) !== -1
          ) != undefined
        );
      this.filtered = [...filtered]
    } else {
      this.filtered = [...this.rows]
    }

    // update the rows
    // Whenever the filter changes, always go back to the first page
    this.table.offset = 0;
  }
```